# Call to master failed org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I am facing following error in simple two machine hadoop cluster.

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Call to master/1.1.1.2:15000 failed on local exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

On master machine my configuration are as.

```
hostname=master
in /etc/hosts
1.1.1.2 master 
1.1.1.3 node1
```

core-site.xml contains

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://master:15000/</value>
</property>
```

In mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
 <value>master:15001</value>
</property>

In conf/master contains
master
In conf/slaves contains
master
node1
```

I have same configuration on node1 except in conf/master,slaves conatins localhost. My OS in CentOS 7. If I run hadoop in single mode, it work properly on both master and node1.

```
Hostname of 
node1 machine is node1 
and in /etc/hosts 
1.1.1.2 master 
1.1.1.3 node1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to flush iptable like

su -c "iptables -F"